# Add value to crypto token

Tags: tokens, bsc, binance

Need help understanding how to add value to the token I made. I want to make it exchangeable for other tokens? I deployed token and added to wallet how do I set its value vs other tokens?

Comment: it is more complicated than that, even if you set a value let's say 1$ for each token? why should I buy your token?

Comment: Thats what i was getting at so how do other coins stake value?